# windows server file permission error when using watchdog

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have a python code that uses watchdog and pandas to automatically upload a newly added excel file once it has been pasted on a given path.
The code works well on my local machine but when I run it to access files on windows server 2012 r 2, I am getting a file permission error. what can be the best solution?

NB: I am able to access the same files using pandas read_excel() without using the watchdog but I want to automate the process so that it auto reads the files every time files are being uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Few possible reasons that you get a permission deny

1. The file has been lock because someone is opening it.
2. Your account doesn't have the permission to read/write/execute